# Does Ruby on Rails nullify session in Graphql Controller from outside domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have a Rails + graphql service running on a different domain, but it seems the session variable in `graphql_controller.rb` is nil. When I run my service locally, the session and context works as expected. Here's an example:

```
# in graphql controller

def execute
  context = {
    session: session,
    test_variable: "has access"
  }
  result = Schema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, ...)
end

# in mutation

def resolve
  ...
  context[:session][:token] = user.token
```

I can easily set the `session[:token]` when both frontend and backend are run locally, but when I point my local to the backend on a different domain, I get a `no method [] for nil` type error when running `context[:session][:token] = user.token`

I'm think the only difference is that the hosted domain is different. Also, the context[:test_variable] is accessible in both cases

graphql/rails suggests

```
  # If accessing from outside this domain, nullify the session
  # This allows for outside API access while preventing CSRF attacks,
  # but you'll have to authenticate your user separately
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

But I would just like to know why this issue is happening

Comment: If your session is stored in cookie, maybe that cookie is limited only to the original domain, so, you in fact don't have the session.